# jQuery add class to certain elements

Tags: jquery, list, dom-manipulation

I have a multilevel menu like this :

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1
    <ul>
      <li>item 1.1</li>
      <li>item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3
    <ul>
      <li>item 3.1</li>
      <li>item 3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

In jQuery I have

```
$("#divId ul li:odd").addClass("blue");
$("#divId ul li:even").addClass("green");
```

The problem is that jQuery adds the class to all the lists.
I would like jQuery to just add the class to the first level (ul > li.class) and NOT the inner childs (ul > li > ul > li.class)

Thanks

Comment: You have a multilevel menu like *THAT*?  Do go on!  Maybe with a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#divId ul:first > li:odd").addClass("blue"); 
$("#divId ul:first > li:even").addClass("green");
```

It will add the classes to the children of the first ul tag found in divId.

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
$("#divId ul li:not(#divId ul li ul li):odd").addClass("blue");
$("#divId ul li:not(#divId ul li ul li):even").addClass("green");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use assumptions here and you you know what they say about them ;)

If you want to add specific classes to all of the ul items then:

```
$('ul').addClass('class-addition');
```

and you can style the list items in the same way.

If you want to add classes to the ul within a li you can use:

```
$('li > ul').addClass('class-addition');
```

using the parent > child selectors.

I'd have a look at the selectors documentation provided by Branislav to find exactly what you want and use firebug to test the results though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, please, give more information on your case. From what I see you need simple select and add class. You can find information on [jquery selectors here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and on [addClass method here](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass)