# How do i append an li and add a i class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Supposed li I want to add an `li` element to an `ul` id , and append the li value with another class which is i

Here's the code

```
<ul class="menu" id="addNotification">                       
     <li>
         <a href="#">
             <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 
         </a>
     </li>                      
 </ul>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(.button).click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addNotification').append($('<li>').text("Something"));
}
```

Before I click the button

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

After I click the button

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a></li>
  <li>"Something"</li>
</ul>
```

I want it to be

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it is always the same?you can use clone if that is the  case

Comment: check this using clone http://jsfiddle.net/rpLzx1wj/

Comment: @guradio it is not flexible, what if I have different data?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4egq8v51/3/

Comment: which data are different need more information try this http://jsfiddle.net/rpLzx1wj/1/

Comment: there many ways to create that but we need more information to help what you really want to get

Comment: Possible duplicate of any of the multitude of similar questions asked in a wide varieties of ways tha tyou can find by just searching SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery add class to certain elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011474/jquery-add-class-to-certain-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consequently create elements and append them:

```js
var $iElement = $("<i/>").addClass('fa fa-users text-aqua');
var $aElement = $("<a/>").append($iElement).append("Something").attr('href', '#');
var $liElement = $("<li/>").append($aElement);
$('#addNotification').append($liElement);

// Just for code demonstration:
$("body").append($("<div/>").text($("#addNotification").html()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addNotification">

</div>
```

Of course, it all can be done in a single line, but it will definitely not improve readability and supportability. Sometimes, longer code is better.

Comment: @JackMoscovi `<i/>` is a self-closing tag which is the same as `<i></i>`. `<i>` is a non-closed tag, which is not correct HTML syntax. Most probably, all modern browsers will close this tag itself, but it isn't a good approach :)

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rpLzx1wj/1/)

Using [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> Description: Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $('#addNotification').find('li').clone();

    $('#addNotification').append(clone);
})
```

Using `.html();`

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var click = $('#addNotification1').find('li').html();

    $('#addNotification1').append("<li>"+click+"</li>");
})
```

Comment: What if I have different data sets? like .text('Something1'), .text('Something 2') , it is based on json data, whenever someone click the button it will append based on that correspond data.

Comment: @JackMoscovi if you are using clone it will copy the exact html

Comment: Thank you for helping, this is close enough but how do set the value of 'Something', since it is just a duplication of the same <li>

Answer (score 0):

So here is your code

```
<ul class="menu" id="addNotification">

 <li>
     <a href="#">
         <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 
     </a>
 </li>

</ul>
```

And in jquery, you can directly append the `li` with its content. And the using `on` is the preferred way to use on click events.

```
$(".button").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addNotification').append('<li>Something</li>');
}
```

Another approach is

```
$(".button").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a>';
    var data = $("<li/>").val(content);
   $('#addNotification').append($(data));
 }
```

Comment: Yeah it is but a different approach.Is it working this way?

Comment: It is the same. = <li>Something</li>, not what I want.

Comment: so this is how you want i guess `<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Something</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this cloning of first `li` to append on every button click

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var liEle = $('#addNotification').find("li:eq(0)").clone();
    $('#addNotification').append(liEle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the new text after the `i` element: (or put it in a string first)

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newthing = $('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i></a></li>');
    newthing.find('i').after("Something2");
    $('#addNotification').append(newthing);
});
```

Lots of other ways also (add class here):

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newthing = $('<li />').append('<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>');
    newthing.find('i').addClass('text-green').after("Something4");
    $('#addNotification').append(newthing);
});
```